# How can I flip (partially mirror) a selection of an image?

Tags: windows-10, macros, mirroring, pictures, flip

I have many pictures. The text in the text balloons is mirrored, or, horizontally flipped. How do I flip this text back so that it is normally readable?

Horizontal flipping  (or mirroring) of the entire page in one go is not an option, because then the sequence of events is wrong. I *strongly* prefer any solution which has a **customizable toolbar**.

If there's no image editor with a built-in function for this, a possible solution might be to do this with a macro containing at least the following commands:

- **select** part of the image (for example, a text balloon)
- **cut** the image-part/partial-image
- **mirror** the image-part
- **paste** image-part **back** in the original place into the image.

... but how do I record this? Is using macros (like those in MS Word) even possible with the image editing programs of today?

**Edit**: OS is Windows 10. I would gladly mention which programs I've tried, or ask which have the capacity for doing this, but since even the tiniest mention of any program will be explained as asking for "opinions" and will be seen, gleefully, as a good excuse for downvotes, I won't do it.

It's also not really necessary. If you know of a program to do this with, feel free to mention this. But I won't. Burned too many times by this site.

[image: partial flipped text]

Comment: What operating system are you using? What image manipulation program are you using?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Windows 10, and it's forbidden to talk about programs on this site

Comment: "Forbidden to talk about programs on this site"? Where do you get that idea? Different image manipulation programs will have different methods to accomplish what you're asking; there's no "generic" way of answering your question without knowing what program you're using.

Comment: Perhaps it's cos I'm a woman I get treated differently (#Monica), but whenever I ask **any**thing about "which program is best to do XYZ?" some dude starts screaming about "how "we don't do program recommendations". If their knickers are REALLY twisted, he'll add something about *we don't help with homework* (to people well into their 50s....mind you), so:   ***Oh. Well.*** ___ P.S. Of course I wasn't really asking for a generic way whatsoever, but I learned the hard way that mentioning specific programs gets one banned/downgraded....But if **YOU** wanna suggest  various programs, please DO SO

Comment: "Which program is best to do XYZ?" and "how can I do XYZ in program A?" are very different questions.

Comment: _"How can I do XYZ in program A?"_ is about solving a problem. _"Which program is best to do XYZ?"_ is about opinions and voting becomes a popularity poll (and please note that "most popular" doesn't necessarily mean "the best"). Some of such questions can be salvaged by removing the subjective part: _"How to do XYZ?"_ is fine.

Comment: @gronostaj which is why i specifically DO NOT ASK that.....

Comment: .... and it would be nice if those advocating for closure either gave reasons for it, or suggestions on how to improve the question. Now, it seems that the closure peeps are doing it for **emo**tional, not **rational** reasons. Or, ideological reasons...

Comment: @gronostaj and asking: *does a program exist with which to do XYZ* would seem fine too, Or even: "With which program can one do XYZ?" Yet, those get burned with a vengeance.

Comment: I suppose the reason for close votes (I didn't vote myself) is what @Jeff said: instructions will differ depending on which program you're using. Technically one could suggest a program and provide instructions for it, but then you may have to install an additional program while one you already have is perfectly capable of doing this too. Ideally you would include names of preferred programs in your question. It won't make it off-topic as long as you're not asking for software recommendation or opinions.

Comment: I will assume (with good reason) that **any** mentioning of any program in whatever way, will just be seen as asking for opinions and an excuse for downvotes. unless someone tells me it's okay to do it,

Comment: There are many questions "how can I do A in B?", with B being `sed` or `awk`, `bash`, `cmd.exe`, Firefox, Chrome, Excel, PuTTY, `nano`, `less`, VLC, `ffmpeg`, Rufus, Albert, … (not all B for the same A, of course). And there are questions like "how can I do A? I'd like a solution for B, but not necessarily for B". Such questions are fine. For many programs we have tags meant to be used in questions. *Telling* us what program(s) you use, can use, want to use, are prone to use, are familiar with, already tried – all this is different than *asking* for software recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Gimp:

1. Use the Selection tools to mark one of the text ballons (e.g. Ellipse mode, hit `e`)
2. Use one of

- Toolbox Flip,
- Menu:Tools > Transform Tools > Flip  or
- `SHIFT`+`F`
  *-- they all have the same effect; tell that you wish to flip things*

3. Click in the selection to actually flip it
4. `Ctrl`+`M` to merge down to a single layer.

*Edit: more detail*

Comment: Can step 2 be achieved by **either** recording-writing a macro.....  **or** via a short-cut? Which then can subsequently be run from a button on the toolbar?

Comment: Step 2: `SHIFT`+`F`

Comment: @Hannu So, no toolbar button, I take it...

Comment: The clickable tool palette (default position is top left) contains a Flip tool, yes, appearance: `[<-|->]` - so Menu, Clickable Tool, and a keyboard shortcut. Your choice which to use: The far quickest is the keyboard.

Comment: Steps 2-4 can probably be scripted, I haven't tried that. e.g. https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html

Comment: if step 4 is needed, can that be avoided by Ctrl-M ing a whole buncha pics in a batch mode thingee?

Comment: Now, please note: I haven't tried gimp scripting so cannot tell about details. But I'd guess; yes. But then; if a bunch of images were prepared for this, then you'd be in a slightly precarious situation; a number of images open and half finished: if something goes wrong, all your work might be lost.

Comment: It's just that I don't need any image to be in a non-single whatever, I don't even know what that is. I'm guessing it's a thing to give pictures higher quality? Therefor, I think you misinterpreted the batch question, since doing a batch job on anything won't leave them open and half finished. In theory, it might but that would be weird. Then imagine a batch process which WON'T do that, then.

Comment: As soon as you edit an image in GIMP in any way you most likely also create at least one extra layer in just doing so (e.g. by the process/description above). This "project" state of image can be saved in e,g. .xcf file format and maybe others. But if you wish to save e.g. an jpg file, the "merge down" may be required; not tried.

Answer (score 1):

### Preface:

Again, I could rely upon the somewhat older, yet free software, of **XnView**. It's French, even. Imagine that. Which is relevant because their different life philosophy allows them to create imaginative and functionally sound software.

### Description:

This is *a* two-step method. Step 1 is to horizontal-flip all the images to their mirrored version in batch. The result of that is visible above in the "intermediate step". Step 2 is to flip the text balloons back. This is done one-by-one, the result of which is visible in the 3rd panel of the picture in the question.

*XnView* can mirror images in batch, and in step 2, one-by-one via a toolbar button and keyboard (Shift+H) The *"trick"* is to use a *macro recorder* for this.

### Workflow

Step 1 consists of:

- Start XnView, open the batch converter with **Ctrl-U**
- Set a destination directory under the `General` tab
- Drag & Drop all of the images into the **"Input"** section. Alternatively, add them via the `Add` or the `Add Folder`-button. In this case, it was a comic book in .CBR format, so I changed the extension to .RAR and unzipped them into a likewise named directory. No doubt there's software which can unzip CBR's, but I don't know them.
- Click on the `Transformations` tab, open the Image branch, select **Flip Horizontal** and double-click it.
- Hit the `Go`-button on the bottom left

Step 2:
Drag and drop all the images into the main XnView window. They will be visible as tabs. Use your favorite  macro recorder to record just two actions: Ctrl-C and Shift-H. Yes, this might seem not useful and trivial, but it does save considerable time and accuracy. Now, I've used one with the über imaginative name of **Macrorecorder** and it can be found at https://www.macrorecorder.com/. It won't surprise no-one that this a not a French outfit, but a German one.

- Open up **Macrorecorder**
- Arrange both windows so that three quarters of your screens' left-hand-side is the XnView and Macrorecorder covers one quarter on the right-hand-side, and arrange it so that the Play, Record and Stop buttons are still visible.
- click on **Record and Edit** at the top of Macrorecorder
- We're just aiming to record **key-strokes**, not any mouse moves/clicks.
- Press Alt-Tab to get the focus back on the XnView window with all the open files.
- Select the desired text inside the text balloon, and if need be, select it line by line.
- Press Ctrl-C and then immediately, Shift-H.
- Press Alt-Tab to get the focus back on **Macrorecorder**
- Stop recording and optionally save the macro, intermediately.
- remove the line which contains the XnView  windows name and remove all the lines with mouse action in them.
- Save the macro for good.

*(A word of warning to those who are looking for freeware macro recorders. It took me surely an hour or more to find one which was not chockfull with viruses or whatever. Even the well known ones with scripting capability like AutoIt, MiniMouseMacro and AutoHotkey had 3 to 7 viruswarnings. I have an unreasonably high fear of getting a frozen computer, so for me, the cut-off line is one warning... some of the time. For some software, the **.exe** will not set off a warning on the more than 70 anti-virus programs of **VirusTotal.com** but their corresponding zipped version will, so check both.)*

### Remark on GIMP

GIMP is a wonderful program, but for this particular case, it's too advanced to use it, it's not fit to do this. I tried the above solution, but one has to press 'R' every time one wants do select a rectangle, Ctrl-M to save intermediate flips per text balloon and it's just too much.
To get the same result in GIMP, there are 7 actions: Press 'R", select the rectangle, press Shift-F (lefthand), click inside the rectangle, let go of the mouse, use righthand to press Ctrl-M , click OK/press Enter. In XnView there are just 2 left-handed keyboard actions.